# Resources - Properties : Possible to dynamically build?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, properties-file

I'm new to Thymeleaf / Spring and have just introduced a message_en.properties file.  I see the benefits of using it, however, it's a bit of a pain to populate it.

I have a form, I've just added several inputs, I know need to add each of these as keys in the message file.  Is there a way of doing this on the fly for me?

Answer (score 0):

To automatically populate the **message properties**, you may have to consider using a scaffolding solution like `jHipster` or something similar.

refer http://jhipster.github.io